# Recursive function - Heap's algorithm function logic

Tags: javascript, recursion, permutation, heaps-algorithm

I'm trying to understand the logic behind this function:

```
 function permAlone(str) {

  arr = str.split("");

  result = [];

  perm(arr, arr.length);
  return result;

  function perm(string, length){
    if (length == 1){
      result.push(string.join(""));
    }

    else {
      for (var i=0; i < length; i++){
       perm(string, length-1);

        if(length % 2 == 0){
         swap(string, i, length-1); 
         }

        else{
         swap(string, 0, length-1);
        }
      }


    }
  }

  function swap(array, first, second){
    var temp = array[first];
    array[first] = array[second];
    array[second] = temp;
  }
}

permAlone('aab');
```

This function returns the permutation of the array passed. It's working but I don't really get how it works. How exactly the result array has a permutations if it has only one push call? also, the perm function gets to be called 4 times or less? I just want to understand the logic of this thing. The swap function is self explanatory. I just have the problem in else statement of the perm function.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: There is certainly more than one `push()`, and depending on the length of the input _almost definitely_ more than 4 calls to `perm()`. I suggest you add `console.log(string)` as your first line of the `perm()` function and then look at the output--that should help you understand.

Comment: @dave, thanks...I've added the console.log..I think I'm getting it now. So, at first function perm iterates until length==1, then it pushes and breaks the function. Then for loop continues, checks if length is even or odd add calls the swap function. after that for iterates and again starts the perm function until the i in the for get to the i==length.